# jQuery slideshow showing an empty slide on the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a slideshow which shows an empty slide after the last element, I think it is something in my script, I think it finds one more child for the element and adds it as an empty space, any ideas? Please find the code attached:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ul = $('.slideshow-content').children();
    var n_img = ul.children().length;
    slide(ul);

    function slide(ul) {
        var i = 1;
        var x = 279;
        setInterval(function() {
            if (i < n_img) {
                pos = x * i + "px";
                ul.animate({
                    right: pos
                }, 700);
                i++;
            } else {
                ul.animate({
                    right: '0px'
                }, 700);
                i = 1;
            }
        }, 3000);
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-content">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="google.com" target="_blank"><img width="279" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRtro3jZRSlrrvwpBxXNznQlkaX7HwAQ45hezfxjXsmwGvVrIfb"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img width="279" src="http://img824.imageshack.us/img824/200/open9j.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img width="279" src="http://assets.huxley.com/engineering/About/sthree.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img width="279" class="hippo-logo" src="http://i.imgur.com/Ti0w8sv.png">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img width="279" src="http://i.imgur.com/QSEcaZ4.jpg">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img width="279" class="optile-logo" src="http://i.imgur.com/H2Tf4E3.jpg">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle of the same

Comment: Not really, it's from a messy tumbler blog codebase :(

Comment: The error must be somewhere else. The provided code runs perfectly:
https://jsfiddle.net/4f8cr6ob/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try (Length-1) in third line of your JS file.

```
var n_img = ul.children().length;
```

Hope this will help

Comment: I checked the length is correct. For given `HTML` length is 6. I don't think this is the issue